# Converting Half-hourly Data to Hourly data by adding the Value columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like below in Excel. The Value1 and Value2 are outputs per half hour (30 mins). I need to add them to get output per hour. Hence, I want to convert the half hourly data to hourly data by adding up the Value1 and Value2 columns for every hour.

| DateTime | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 00:30:00.000 | 5 | 10 |
| 2022-02-01 01:00:00.000 | 6 | 20 |
| 2022-02-01 01:30:00.000 | 14 | 30 |
| 2022-02-01 02:00:00.000 | 10 | 40 |

The expected result table is as below:

| DateTime | Value1 | Value2 | Output1 | Output2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 00:30:00.000 | 5 | 10 |  |  |
| 2022-02-01 01:00:00.000 | 6 | 20 | 11 | 30 |
| 2022-02-01 01:30:00.000 | 14 | 30 |  |  |
| 2022-02-01 02:00:00.000 | 10 | 40 | 24 | 70 |

Please can someone help me out by suggesting formula/etc in Execel. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `F2`, formula copied right to `G2` and all copied down :

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,$A:$A,">="&($E2-"0:30"),$A:$A,"<="&$E2)
```

[image]